# Image Resize, Rotate, Move with touch with something around the Image

Tags: android, photo, android-library

Is there any library or any code or any helpful link to do re-size,rotate,move an image by touch?something that stick around the photo.

Comment: something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cz2rgLcfTNg